# How to use Aeotec Nano Dimmer with a SPST switch?

Tags: dimmer

I have an Aeotec Nano Dimmer, and am trying to understand how to dim lights using an external SPST switch connected to it.

If I toggle the switch the lights go on and off.

If I toggle it and then toggle it back instantly, the light level starts to change, but it seems quite erratic: I can't reliably stop it.

The documentation is silent about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your third paragraph.  For clarity, do you mean that when you toggle it back and forth rapidly, the light stays stuck partially dimmed?

Comment: @anonymous2: Toggle once: light turns on (or off, depending on the current state) via dimming.

Toggle twice rapidly: light level starts to change sometimes. If I toggle it twice again, the light level stops to change (sometimes). Otherwise I don't see any pattern.

Toggle more than twice rapidly: chaotic response, I haven't found any patterns in how the dimmer reacts.

Comment: You're supposed to use a *momentary* pushbutton for dimming, not an ordinary toggle or rocker lightswitch.  See the user guide which explains how to configure the switch mode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yep, I have tested dimming with a momentary pushbutton, and it works well in this configuration. I have read the user guide many times, and while it tells how to configure the switch mode, it is completely silent about operating the switches afterwards.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are trying to do something that is not supported.  As you say, it works fine with the the momentary pushbotton type of switch that is *supposed* to be used for dimming.   It doesn't seem like dimming is supposed to work with other types of switches.

Comment: Hmm, how do you know the supported modes? Am I missing some manual published by Aoetec that describes how the dimmer is to be operated with different kinds of switches? Also, momentary pushbuttons I have found are all supposed to be doorbell buttons, I have a hard time finding one without a small bell engraved, and all dimmers I have found have a rotating knob.

Comment: What you are missing is that the documentation specifically describes dimming with a pushbutton, and on/off control with a switch.  There's no basis in the documentation for believing that dimming is supposed to work with a switch.  You've observed that it provides no instructions for dimming with a switch, but yet to come to the realization that it is unmentioned *because it is not supported*.

Comment: Well, the docs don't say that the dimming works with momentary pushbutton either, but it does. Actually, the docs don't say _anything_ about operating external buttons. The dimmer may launch nuclear rockets if a SPDT switch is connected and toggled for all I know.

Comment: The fact is that the information is there in the documentation.  Apparently you preferred to make a support request, but it was there for me to read, and I've never touched the product or contacted the company.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Where is the documentation you've found it, could you give me an URL? I have now received the answer, but I still can't find it anywhere in the docs, and googling snippets of the answer does not return anything useful either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have received the following answer from Aeotec support:

> Standard Toggle Switch using 2-state Mode:
>   - Toggle once - toggles last dim level / OFF.
>
> Standard Toggle Switch using Momentary Mode:
>
> Just to note, you must control the 2-state switch as if it were a
>   momentary push button where tapping a momentary button is much like
>   toggling a 2-state switch 2x times quickly, or pressing and holding is
>   like flipping the switch once, then flipping the switch again is like
>   releasing the momentary push button.
>
> - Toggle twice quickly - toggles last dim level / OFF.
> - Toggle once - Acts like press and hold, ramps light up and down
>
>   - Toggle one more time - Acts like you are releasing a push button, stops the ramping
>
> For the second use case, you must force set Nano Dimmer to see the
>   toggle switch as a momentary switch.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer isnt quite correct in its conclusion.  You cant make the dimmer see a toggle switch as momentary.  Sure, you can configure it to be momentary, but it's still a toggle switch. And the problem just changes, it does not go away.

The solution is to use a momentary switch.

- Every time the switch is pressed, it toggles the light.
- If the switch is held down, the light intensifies. And you release it at the desired brightness  The next time it is held down, the light dims.
- If the switched is pressed twice the light goes to max brightness.